# How to add sql ODBC DLL drivers to my advanced installer project

Tags: c#, sql-server, advanced-installer

I am looking for `.dll` files for **sql server ODBC** in my computer and i can't find it. I want it to add in my advanced installer project, because I have a `c#` app that use sql server client and first of all I need to install Native Sql server 2014 on my customer's computer.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html

Comment: Yes, but its about installing SQL server Express, while I need to install SQL Server 2014 with my Database and its tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add and install the DLLs of the SQL SERVER ODBC driver to your setup. All Windows OSes come with the ODBC drivers preinstalled.

The only standalone ODBC driver redistributable for SQL Server are [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 and 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730314(v=sql.110).aspx) If you need to install these new ODBC drivers, then you can add them alongside the SQL Native Client setup in the "Prerequisites" page of your Advanced Installer setup project. They can be added as prerequisites.